# Is my ISP throttling the bandwidth of my Tor relay?

Tags: exit-relays, bandwidth

I am operating a Tor relay (OR) as an exit on a 10 MB/s speed network. But when checking from atlas.torproject.org, it shows only 1 MB/s Advertised Bandwidth. Is it that my ISP is throttling my bandwidth for Tor network?

I have set 10485760 for RelayBandwidthRate and MaxAdvertisedBandwidth.

Comment: This is hardly a throttling from your ISP, since you're referring to *advertised* (as opposed to real) bandwidth. What is your *Consensus Weight*? When did you start the server? Can you post your OR identification?

Comment: The units for network bandwidth, except in the Tor context, are generally bits per second. In the Tor context, units are bytes per second. There are eight bits per byte. "10 MB/s" is not a standard bandwidth. Standard bandwidths are 10 Mbps (1.25 MB/s) and 100 Mbps (12.5 MB/s). Might that be the issue?