# How can I know whether my ISP is limiting Tor on its bandwidth

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, bandwidth

My question is not a duplicate of this [question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/is-my-isp-throttling-the-bandwidth-of-my-tor-relay) as in that it is asked only about Tor relay and the user has not given perfect bandwidth allocation of the ISP.

You can normally check whether your ISP is blocking the Torrent download by simply seeing the download speed (which is way less then your real speed i.e. 60Kbps instead of 6Mbps)but how can I check whether Tor is being limited or restricted by the ISP ?

Is there any method to check whether my ISP is really into blocking / limiting my Tor usage (Tor usage may include setting up a relay and/or exit nodes) traffic which is done either through the Tor software or the browser bundle

If at all the ISP is serious in blocking / limiting it's bandwidth  for Tor then what are the steps to be taken to free my self from this limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aurora says, just test using speed-test sites. [SpeedOf.me](http://speedof.me/) is good because it uses HTML5 rather than Javascript. Test several times, stopping and starting the Tor browser between tests, in order to use different circuits. In that way, you can distinguish ISP bandwidth limitation from circuit to circuit variation.

It may be possible to overcome bandwidth limitations by using obfuscated bridges. If you haven't used obfuscated bridges before, it's probably best to start with a fresh Tor browser folder. Start Tor browser, and click the "Configure" button for bridge etc. settings. Answer "No" about needing proxy and firewall, and "Yes" about ISP censorship. Check the "My ... ISP blocks connections ..." box, select obfs3 transport type, and then hit OK. If Tor won't connect, make sure that you have a working Python install, and try again.

Comment: ok but what about the last part of my question in steps to overcome the bandwidth limit.

Comment: The second paragraph covers suggested steps (using obfuscated bridges) to overcome bandwidth limits if they're being applied to the tor protocol

Comment: Yes, it does. But I haven't tested that in Windows. Maybe someone can, and either edit the answer or comment.

Comment: And how to do the same if its for uTorrent downloads

Answer (score 1):

To do this, just go to any download speed website, and check out your upload and download times.  Keep in mind when you do this, that your speed will be lower than your normal speed.  For example, I have a 11 up and 30 down, but with Tor I have 9 up and 20 down.